# Replace char by coma and substrate 1 to the third value in JS

Tags: javascript, string

Supposing I have this:

```
var date = '2017-06-02';
```

How can I get:

```
var date = '2017,5,2';
```

---

So, I need to :

- replace the `-` by `,`
- remove the leading zero if applied for the first and second parameter.
- remove 1 for the second value

Thanks so much.

Comment: remove 1 for the second value?

Comment: If I have `06`, it should be `5`.

Comment: What if there is a leading zero in the day or year and not just the month?

Comment: Hello @nnnnnn, only for the first and second element. I've edit my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var date = '2017-06-22';

var parts = date.split("-");      // split by '-' to get an array of parts

parts[0] = +parts[0];             // convert to number to remove any leading 0's

parts[1]--;                       // increment or decrement the part you need

parts[2] = +parts[2];             // convert to number to remove any leading 0's

var newDate = parts.join(",");    // join the parts together using ','

console.log(newDate);
```

`parts[1]--` is the same as `parts[1] = parts[1] - 1` (`parts[1]` is the second part i.e. '06'). The parts ar strings, but whe using an operator that only applies on numbers such as `-`, then the part get converted to a number. If you use the `+` operator, however, this will cause a problem, as `+` wil be regarded as string concatination and not as numerical addition. A safter appraoch is to convert the string to a number first (either implicitly using `unary +` operator, or explicitly using `parseInt` or `Number`):

```
parts[1] = parseInt(parts[1]) - or + theNumberYouWant;
```

Comment: Is it faster than the Norbert option ?

Comment: That's like asking if a ladybug is faster than a grasshopper.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a regular expression based [string replacement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). The following uses capturing groups to get the year, month and day, then [uses a function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) to produce the replacement text.

```js
var date = '2017-06-02';

var output = date.replace(/(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/, function(_, y, m, d) {
  return y + ',' + (m - 1) + ',' + +d;
});

console.log(output);
```

The result of the subtraction on the month is a number not a string, so it drops any leading zero automatically, then for the day I've used the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Unary_plus_()) to convert it to a number to drop its leading zero (if present), and both are concatenated into a string with the required commas.

Answer (score 0):

Non-ninjutsu solution:

```
var date = '2017-06-02';

var y = date.split("-")[0];
var m = date.split("-")[1];
var d = date.split("-")[2];

var final = y + "," + (parseInt(m)-1) + "," + parseInt(d);

console.log(final);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var date = '2017-06-02'

function convertDate(date){
var ddmmyy = date.split('-');
var withRemovedZero = ddmmyy.map(function(x){return parseInt(x)});
withRemovedZero[1] = withRemovedZero[1] -1;
return withRemovedZero.join(",");
}

console.log(convertDate(date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split` you can do that.

```js
var date = '2017-06-02';
var date_array = date.split("-");
var first = date_array[1].charAt(0);
if(first=='0'){
    first = date_array[1].substr(1);
}
else{
    first = date_array[1];
}
var second = date_array[2].charAt(0);
if(second=='0'){
    second = date_array[2].substr(1);
}
else{
    second = date_array[2];
}
var output = date_array[0]+","+first+","+second;
document.write(output);
```

Output,

```
2017,6,2 // If date is 2017-06-02
2017,12,24 // If date is 2017-12-24
```

Comment: What about subtracting 1 from the month?